# Explain how to find the equation of a tangent line to a curve using differential calculus and explain why such a line is useful.

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

Q.  Explain how to find the equation of a tangent line to a curve using differential calculus and explain why such a line is useful?

I know the usual process to find the equation of tangent line. The process is, find a derivative of the function at that point, which will be the slope of the tangent line at that point. Then we use the point-slope formula to point the equation of the tangent.

I am a little bit confused about the use of that tangent line. Could you please explain to me, what is use of this tangent line?

Comment: the tangent line is a good, simple approximation to the curve close to the point

Comment: Any standard calculus text should contain an extended discussion of the applications of the derivative and the tangent line.

Comment: Where does this question come from?  Are you at the end of a specific chapter or lecture?

Comment: A particular use of the tangent line is to approximate roots of an equation via [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_calculus#Applications_of_derivatives